# Why Google physicalweb.googleapis.com doesn't resolve https address working on Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, https

We have an Elastic Load Balancer, and behind that we have an EC2 server instance. We have a certificate that was issued by Amazon Certificate manager, which protects our *.domain.com, and is assigned to the load balancer. We have our DNS configured so that requests to *.domain.com are sent to the load balancer. So www.domain.com over https goes to load balancer, which then goes to EC2 server which should get the website. This works in the web browser - we can see a website - but not in the physical web browser chrome://physical-web in Chrome on Android (get UNRESOLVED status only for this address, direct links to let's say www.paypal.com are resolved correctly) and url validator tool responds "URL not found": https://beaufortfrancois.github.io/sandbox/physical-web/url-validator/

Answer (score 0):

robots.txt must exist at the server to pass validation over google api and be resolved in Chrome browser.